# How to achieve this in reactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pull data from Local json into a table.This is initial table:
[Before Clicking Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmKpM.png)

Once you click show the table becomes like this:
[After Clicking show label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IinzY.png)

ON click of show the detailed values of first row will be displayed below the first row

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use libraries for the this purpose their are multiple libraries in react for tables operations like [`react table`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table) and [`react-flexy-table`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-flexy-table)